# Redux Presentational Components only for top level components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm wondering whether Presentational Components should be use only in top level components or not?

For example: I've got component `Layout` which includes deeper components such as `Sidebar` and `Content`, going forward `Content` component includes components `Header` and `Conversation`.

Each component (excludes Layout and Content) should be connected to tore as Presentational Components?

```
+----------------------+
|         LAYOUT       |
|+---+-----------------+
|| S |     CONTENT     |
|| I |+---------------+|
|| D ||    HEADER     ||
|| E |+---------------+|
|| B ||               ||
|| A || CONVERSATION  ||
|| R ||               ||
|+---++---------------+|
+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no clear definition of what types of components need to be presentational/container, I prefer smart/dumb.


It all depends on how you handle the data binding and action handlings in them

From [Presentational and Container Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.kldlzw4j4) by Dan Abramov

> When to Introduce Containers?
>   I suggest you to start building your app with just presentational components first. Eventually you’ll realize that you are passing too many props down the intermediate components. When you notice that some components don’t use the props they receive but merely forward them down and you have to rewire all those intermediate components any time the children need more data, it’s a good time to introduce some container components. This way you can get the data and the behavior props to the leaf components without burdening the unrelated components in the middle of the tree.

Comment: Ok, now its clear for me. I just thought that connecting each component to store is wrong solution.

Comment: Use `connect()` wherever it makes sense for your own app.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-multiple-components